# Python Web-scraping charmap issue, works fine in IDLE not in ATOM IDE? why?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, utf-8, urllib

While doing simple url read request from python. I have encountered the follow issue in my Atom IDE, while doing in idle I didn't receive the error, what may be the reason for it. Below is the code.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
html = urlopen("https://morvanzhou.github.io/static/scraping/basic-structure.html").read().decode('utf-8')
print(html)
```

Below is the error:
    [image]

Answer (score 0):

That's most likely happening because Atom's terminal is expecting an encoding while python is encoding that html to another encoding. Are you using Atom on Windows?

To solve that try either configuring your Atom terminal to the encoding of your system or encode html to utf8:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
html = urlopen("https://morvanzhou.github.io/static/scraping/basic-structure.html").read().decode('utf-8')
print(html.encode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: Ya running on windows. Instead of encode('utf-8') . I can simply delete the decode function in the second line. Any idea how to configure to system encoding?

Comment: Im not sure what terminal youre using

Comment: Hi, I am using windows.